# secure struts2 actions with spring security3

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

i work on an app written with struts2 and spring 3 and spring security 3.1. I have setup spring security and works fine if i use annotation @PreAuthorize in my service layer, but when i want to use this at a struts action:

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('RIGHT_CREATE')")
    public String doSomething(){
        System.out.print("been there done that");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

i get an error like this:

```
Stacktraces
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy221.doSomething()

    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.getActionMethod(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:75)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:47)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

i guess that this has something to so with the fact that my action class does not implements an interface and i use JDKProxy not cglib, and spring cannot generate a proxy for this action in order to apply the annotation...

PS. i have

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>
```

in my struts.xml.

my question is: how can i "fix" this ? is it wise to mix cglib(for spring security) and jdkproxy(spring DI) in the same project ? what would be an elegant solution ?

Comment: Yes exactly that. "spring cannot generate a proxy for this action in order to apply the annotation...". So what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

In struts 2, Action classes can't detect the annotations other than predefined struts2 annotations,
you can make use if these annotations at service layer but you can't make use of these annotations at action layer(Presentation layer).

Comment: it works with struts2 actions if i add cglib to my classpath.